# VS code issues with whitespaces in filenames

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had a heck of a time troubleshooting a broken image link in Jekyll, and it turns out that because of white spaces in the filename, VS Code appended a non-printing encoding character [U+200] at the beginning of the filename.

I had to copy the path from GitHub and paste into VS Code to see the character. Can anyone tell me why VS Code doesn't seem to like white spaces in a filename?

Comment: how are you sure that VS Code was the one that added that character?